# How to rotate an image within a StackPanel or Grid in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an image control sits inside a Grid control. I already have a button to enable zoom-in to this image. After zoom-in, the Horizontal/vertical scroll bars are displayed. And then I rotate the image contained grid, the image and the grid scroll bar are messed up. How should I incorporate both zoom-in and rotate for the image control? The following are the code that I am using in my project.

The image control zoom-in code I used (x is the image control):

```
if ((x as Image) != null) { x.Height = x.Height * 1.3; x.Width = x.Width * 1.3; }
```

The rotation code I used (x is the image control):

```
if ((x as Image) != null)
{    
    RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform(); rotate.Angle = rotateAngle;
    rotate.CenterX = x.Width / 2;
    rotate.CenterY = x.Height / 2;
    x.RenderTransform = rotate;                                       
};
```

The XAML is:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Height="480" Width="615"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ScrollViewer.Content>
      <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid">
          <StackPanel x:Name="ImageStackPanel">
              <Image Source="..." VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="220" Height="170" ></Image>  
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Does anybody have any existing code snippet that I can borrow to resolve this trick?

Comment: Can you post your XAML too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [TransformGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx) to use more than one transform at the time:

```
        ScaleTransform myScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        myScaleTransform.ScaleY = 3;

        RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
        myRotateTransform.Angle = 45;

        // Create a TransformGroup to contain the transforms 
        // and add the transforms to it.
        TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myScaleTransform);
        myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myRotateTransform);

        // Associate the transforms to the image.
        x.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for your needs:

```
  <Image x:Name="image" Source="myImageSource" Stretch="Uniform" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                 <Image.RenderTransform>
                     <TransformGroup>
                         <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotate"/>
                         <ScaleTransform x:Name="Scale" />
                     </TransformGroup>
                 </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>
```

code behind:

```
  Rotate.Angle = 45;
  Scale = 0.25;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my image control doesn't have the LayoutTransform attribute. Are you using WPF or Silverlight. I am using Silverlight.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed Silverlight would have LayoutTransform aswell :(

Comment: Updated with possible silverlight solution

Comment: Thanks, sa_ddam213. But still no luck. I forgot to say that I have a ScrollViewer outside the grid control. I used the following code:

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the `LayoutTransformer` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), and the `AnimationMediator`  from [one of the Toolkit developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/04/10/a-bit-more-er-than-meets-the-eye-easily-animate-and-update-layouttransformer-with-animationmediator.aspx).

With the `LayoutTransformer` you can set its content to anything, not just images, and apply any transformation with it, and as opposed to the usual `RenderTransform`, it will affect layout and actual sizes.

I have a similar scenario and I use it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <fs:AnimationMediator x:Name="RotateMediator" LayoutTransformer="{Binding ElementName=LayoutTransformer}" AnimationValue="{Binding Angle, ElementName=RotateTransform, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <fs:AnimationMediator x:Name="ScaleXMediator" LayoutTransformer="{Binding ElementName=LayoutTransformer}" AnimationValue="{Binding ScaleX, ElementName=ScaleTransform, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <fs:AnimationMediator x:Name="ScaleYMediator" LayoutTransformer="{Binding ElementName=LayoutTransformer}" AnimationValue="{Binding ScaleY, ElementName=ScaleTransform, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <tkt:LayoutTransformer x:Name="LayoutTransformer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <tkt:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateTransform" />
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </tkt:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>

        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="mysource.png" Width="600" Height="800" />

    </tkt:LayoutTransformer>
</Grid>
```

Because of the lack of MultiBinding you'd probably additionally have to manually handle the input value (from Slider controls etc) changed events and then set the AnimationValues of `RotateMediator` etc accordingly.